# Using Watir's .click inside of Bootstrap's popover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, twitter-bootstrap, watir, watir-webdriver

In Watir I am attempting to access an `a` element that appears inside of a popover supplied by Bootstrap.

Just calling `a(:class, 'my_link').click` didn't want to play ball, so I added the line `a(:class, 'my_link').wait_until_present` hoping that it was maybe a timing issue between clicking on the element that generates the popover and accessing its contents, but this just times out after 30 seconds and returns that the element never becomes present.

During the time it is waiting I am able to open up code inspector and confirm that the element does exist and is clickable.

I should mention, that manually doing the steps Watir should be doing works.

#### My current thinking

I know when I was trying to interact with this element using jQuery that using a regular `.click();` wouldn't work and instead I had to call `$('body').on('click', ',my_link');` could something similar be at play here?

It might be something to do with the element incorrectly being classed as not visible.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

#### Code

Here is the generated code from inside the popover:

```
<div class="popover fade bottom in" style="top: 40px; left: 424px; display: block;">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="popover-inner">
    <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
    <!-- SNIP -->
      <p>
        <a class="my_link">My Link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The popover is generated by a click;

```
$('.nav-popup').popover('show');
```

Here is the relevant part of the Watir test;

```
span(:class, 'nav-popup').click
a(:class, 'my_link').wait_until_present
a(:class, 'my_link').click
```

To check that I can interact with the popover I added the following to my Watir test;

```
quick_log = a(:class, 'my_link').html
binding.pry
```

And when pry opened I could see that `quick_log` contains the correct HTML content, which is annoying because the very next line is  `a(:class, 'my_link').wait_until_present` which it gacks out on.

#### Error Messages

The line

```
a(:class, 'my_link').click
```

Generates;

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the part of the page that reproduces the problem and/or find an example page online that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have added in the relevant parts, unfortunately I couldn't find anywhere online to recreate this.

Comment: Can you do any interaction with the popup? For example, get the text of the popup?

Comment: Yes, I have just expanded my question (thanks for your help by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your answer, then rather than two lines of code I'd simply do

```
browser.div(:class, 'popover-content').a(:class, 'my_link').click
```

Given that is being created dynamically by javascript, you might have to toss in some stuff to sync and wait for the element to come into being

```
browser.div(:class, 'popover-content').when_present.a(:class, 'my_link').click
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition, in my case I wanted to use `container` again later on the in code so it made sense for me, but as a one liner yours makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something to do with the way bootstrap generates the popover, it must clone it from somewhere which means when I was doing `a(:class, 'my_link').click` it was finding hidden version which the actual popover gets cloned from.

To fix this I changed `a(:class, 'my_link').click` to

```
container = div(:class, 'popover-content')
container.a(:class, 'my_link').click
```

This makes it more specific and avoids the duplicate element being found.